# Memory Consistency Properties explanation

Tags: java, multithreading, memory

I am looking at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility and having trouble understanding what this means - "All actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully returns from a join on that thread." Can I please get an example on what this means and what is the happen-before guarantee in the example.

Comment: What exactly about it are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: I have similar difficulty to understand the statement "successfully returns from a join", join return void, so maybe the statement should be "actions after join method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have he following code

```
public class Test {

 public static int i = 1;
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  System.out.println("Start main");
  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("Start second");
      i = 10;
    }
  });
  t.start();
  t.join();
  System.out.println("After join");
  System.out.println(i); //should print 10
 }
}
```

Everything which is done inside `run()` method happens before main thread gets control back from `t.join();`. That is why static variable `i` will have value `10` when printed in main thread.